# How to run play commands? I am getting the error "play FAIL formats: can't open input file"

Tags: playframework, command, installation

I downloaded the zip file of play-2.2.1 . After, I extracted it and trying to run the play executable , but it says 
"play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.8.0_20), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com."

I tried the command by giving path to the play executable from my home directory(play-2.2.1 is in my Downloads) then it worked(./Downloads/play-2.2.1/play new myapp) and generated a new app. But any play command like play ~run etc... are not working. I think this issue was related to some path issues.But I don't know how to resolve. Can anyone help me out of this ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: What platform are you running this command on?

Comment: I just created a new application using `play new app` . After that how to proceed ? I don't know what you are asking about.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *NIX platforms you can create an alias for play binary by adding

```
alias play="~/Downloads/play-2.2.1/play"
```

to your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` if you are using zsh)

After that you may go in any folder and just type `play new` to interractively create a new play application.

When the application is created, type `play run` in the same folder to run the application on localhost.

Since 2.2.x there is another way to create an application by using Typesafe Activator, here you may find the tutorial on creation of your first application with it https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication

Comment: It was giving this error

`bash: alias: play: not found`
`bash: alias: =: not found`
`bash: alias: ~/Downloads/play-2.2.1/play: not found`

Comment: Remove the spaces around "=" in the line with alias

Comment: .. and restart the bash by typing "bash" in the command line after saving the .bashrc file

Comment: yeah ..its working. After this how to run on localhost?

Comment: Go in the root folder of the created application and run "play run"  in the command line. After that open http://localhost:9000 with your browser.

Comment: I have Java-eclipse.How can I open this created application in that?

Comment: In the root folder type "play" then "eclipse" in play console. This will create eclipse project from your application that you will be able to open with your ide. More on that here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

Comment: How can I open that in eclipse?

Comment: As explained in the link I gave you: "You then need to import the application into your Workspace with the File/Import/General/Existing project… menu (compile your project first)."

Comment: OK, Thanks for your help @Mironor.  Is their anyother way to keep in touch with you.

Comment: If you don't find an answer for your problem in docs for some time, feel free to create a new question here with "playframework" tag, I have a filter for them. I'm at work now so there won't be immediate repsonse, but I'll see your question eventually.